# Running "haxe build.hxml" command gives me "permission denied" error

Tags: c#, command-line, haxe

I installed Haxe following instructions on this website:
https://haxe.org/documentation/platforms/csharp.html

I did literally everything as is written there, I installed Haxe Compiler, then C# support for Haxe using command-line, then VSCode with Haxe extension pack, created a project with the exact structure they mentioned there and then I used VSCode to write Main.hx file. Everything went smoothly until I tried running

```
haxe build.hxml
```

command. I was prompted with the following error:

```
Sys_error("bin/cs/hxcs_build.txt: Permission denied")
```

I really don't know what could be wrong. I restarted my PC, but got the same error. I made sure I run cmd.exe as admin. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out my antivirus kept deleting the file without sending any notification, so I didn't know about it.